# AndroidX crashes on MultiSelectListPreference

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-preferences, androidx

I am having trouble getting Jetpack/AndroidX preferences to work with `MultiSelectListPreference`. I have reduced my code down to the **simplest example project here: https://github.com/quittle/a11y-ally/tree/simple-multi-list**.

For some reason, the most basic Activity with a single preference fragment with a single, empty MultiSelectListPreference crashes when using the AndroidX classes, but doesn't with the vanilla Android APIs that have been deprecated in Android SDK level 28.

I have found https://code.videolan.org/videolan/vlc-android/commit/1464d1a6ab882eec78ab3a749e8f06e52bbd7404, which seems to indicate this may be an issue with the AppCompat libraries, but doesn't fix my setup when adapted to use the AndroidX libraries.

Minimal code snippets of code consuming the Preferences

#### Works

```
public class VanillaMainActivity extends Activity {
    public static class CustomPreferenceFragment extends PreferenceFragment {
        @Override
        public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
        }
    }

    public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);

        getFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.preferences_holder, new CustomPreferenceFragment())
            .commit();
    }
}
```

#### Crashes

```
public class AndroidXMainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    public static class CustomPreferenceFragment extends PreferenceFragmentCompat {
        @Override
        public void onCreatePreferences(final Bundle savedInstanceState, final String rootKey) {
            addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
        }
    }

    public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);

        getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.preferences_holder, new CustomPreferenceFragment())
                .commit();
    }
}
```

The stacktrace I get when using the AndroidX library is below.

```
2018-11-05 20:32:22.318 18080-18080/com.example E/com.example: Invalid ID 0x00000000.
2018-11-05 20:32:22.320 18080-18080/com.example E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example, PID: 18080
    android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0
        at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.getValue(ResourcesImpl.java:216)
        at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2155)
        at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:1155)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:421)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AlertController$AlertParams.createListView(AlertController.java:989)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AlertController$AlertParams.apply(AlertController.java:965)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog$Builder.create(AlertDialog.java:982)
        at androidx.preference.PreferenceDialogFragmentCompat.onCreateDialog(PreferenceDialogFragmentCompat.java:158)
        at androidx.fragment.app.DialogFragment.onGetLayoutInflater(DialogFragment.java:330)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performGetLayoutInflater(Fragment.java:1308)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1460)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1784)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1852)
        at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:802)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2625)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2411)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2366)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2273)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:733)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After filing the bug report, I was informed that the reason it was failing was I didn't have an App Compat theme like `Theme.AppCompat` on the activity, hence the missing resource exception. After adding that to the activity, it works as expected.

Comment: I added the attribute `<item name="alertDialogTheme">@style/Theme.AppCompat.Dialog.Alert</item>` on the parent theme and it works. Only affects the theme of alert dialogs.